# Flutter change UI with platform channels

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-platform-channel

I want to use platform channel to change UI(ui.image) to update modified image faster(my app have delay with this).
Is it able to change UI with platform channel?
If it is, how can I specify changing ui and apply change to platform channel?

---

EDIT

I want to pass bytedata and show it through navite imageview

Comment: Do you want to change something by checking platform ?

Comment: no, I want to pass byte data and show it through platform's native imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
```

ex:

```
Platform.isIOS ? Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios):Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
```